# Bar chart using Dictionaries in python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have two Dictionaries:

```
A = {2018: 23, 2019: 30}
B = {2018: 26, 2019:35}
```

Now I want to plot trend for 2018/2019 for A and B. however when plotting the bar graph, I am getting the following result. The years are expanding to fill space and b is hiding out A completely. Please suggest how to plot the graph.

[image]

The original data have Average marks for maths, science, and total which I want to plot on the same graph (bar graph) for two years to show the trend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can align the bars of a bar graph by their left of right edge (pass a negative width to align using the right edge) - in this way you can get side-by-side bars. Alternatively you can stack the bars.

Here is the code with the output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = {2018: 23, 2019:30}
B = {2018: 26, 2019:35}

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,5))

ax1.bar(A.keys(), A.values(), width=0.2, align='edge', label='A')
ax1.bar(B.keys(), B.values(), width=-0.2, align='edge', label='B')
ax1.set_xticks([2018, 2019])
ax1.set_xlabel('YEAR')
ax1.legend()

ax2.bar(A.keys(), A.values(), width=0.4, align='center', label='A')
ax2.bar(B.keys(), B.values(), bottom=[A[i] for i in B.keys()], width=0.4, align='center', label='B')
ax2.set_xticks([2018, 2019])
ax2.set_xlabel('YEAR')
ax2.legend()

fig.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you start to deal with more data it makes sense to use a package that can handle data more easily. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great package that will do this for you.

Here is an example with 4 sets of time-series data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

A = {2018: 23, 2019:30}
B = {2018: 26, 2019:35}
C = {2018: 30, 2019:40}
D = {2018: 20, 2019:50}

df = pd.DataFrame([A,B,C,D], index=['A','B','C','D']).transpose()

fig, ax= plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,5))

df.plot.bar(ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('YEAR')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

The output is this figure:
[image]

Comment: thanks A lot, Robbie, Wanted to ask, what if I had 3 Variables to be plotted (A, B, C). How would we adjust the width?

Comment: Hi @ApoorvaaSingh - check out the edit, hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful :)

Comment: Also, if you could tell me how would i rotate the Xlabels (i tried using ax.set_xticklabels(rotation = 90), does not seem to work

Comment: Sure, you have to add that argument to the call to the panda's bar function: df.plot.bar(ax=ax, rot=0)