# How to make a grouped bar chart with multiple data for the same x_label string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I'm doing the post-process of an analysis.
Basically, for each analysis (=folder), I go through csv files and gather the maximum displacement of the isolated model, and of the assembled model.

I created three lists :

- analysis : Gather the analysis name, made of the two-component that varies with each analysis (=folder)
- max_disp_iso : Maximum displacement for the isolated csv
- max_disp_asb : Maximum displacement for the isolated csv

But for each analysis (=folder), I'll either have only one csv for each case (one isolated and one assembled), or three assembled csv and one isolated one.
That leaves us with up to 1 (case when I have only one csv in the folder) + 3 (case when I have three csv in the folder) = 4 couples of values stored in max_disp_iso and max_disp_asb that will relate to different entries in analysis list but with the same name.

What I would like, is to create a grouped bar chart that would plot these results for each same analysis string, this kind of chart :
[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0hKR.png)

My code is :

```
def max_displacement_lis(model):
    """Gather max displacement from lis and compare them for each analysis.

    Args:
        model (list): List of dictionnaries containing list of path.
    """
    # Nom du sous-dossier de post-traitement
    folder_name = "lis_vs_asb"

    # Création d'un dossier pour le stockage des résultats
    util.folder_creation(folder_name)

    # Saving of max. displacements
    analysis = []
    max_disp_iso = []
    max_disp_asb = []

    # Browsing of all the analyses (folders) carried out one after the other
    for couple in model:

        # Namming the result which will be saved as .png
        fig_title, fig_path = util.export_spec(
            couple['folder_path'],
            folder_name)

        # Creating a figure with or without horizontal subplots
        fig, axs = util.subplot_creator(len(couple['asb_path']), 1, fig_title)

        # Recuperation du nombre de fichiers (= nombre de hauteurs de lisses)
        n = len(couple['asb_path'])

        # Loop through files in analysis folder
        for i in range(n):

            # Backward browsing of indices to position the graphs
            j = n - i - 1

            # Reading csv files with headers
            lisse = pd.read_csv(couple['liso_path'][0], index_col=0)
            asb = pd.read_csv(couple['asb_path'][i], index_col=0)
            res = pd.concat(
                [lisse, asb['NODE_LIS_CENTRE_' + str(i + 1)]], axis=1)

            # Gathering analysis short name
            pot_sec = substring_after(couple['folder_path'], 'pot_IPE')
            lis_sec = substring_after(couple['folder_path'], 'lis_IPE')
            pot_sec = pot_sec[:3]
            lis_sec = lis_sec[:3]
            name = 'IPE_' + pot_sec + '\n' + 'IPE_' + lis_sec

            # Appending results to lists
            analysis.append(name)
            max_disp_iso.append(max(lisse['NODE_LIS_ISO']))
            max_disp_asb.append(max(asb['NODE_LIS_CENTRE_' + str(i + 1)]))

            # Récupération du nom du fichier csv utilisé comme titre de figure
            fig_subtitle = os.path.basename(couple['asb_path'][i])

            # Plot des résultats sur la figure
            # util.results_plotter(res, n, j, fig, axs, fig_subtitle)

        # Enregistrement au format .png
        plt.savefig(fig_path)

    x = np.arange(len(analysis))
    width = 0.35
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 5])
    rects1 = axs.bar(analysis, max_disp_iso, width, label='max_disp_iso')
    rects2 = axs.bar(analysis, max_disp_asb, width, label='max_disp_asb')
    axs.set_ylabel('Displacement (m)')
    axs.set_title('Max displacement')
    # axs.set_xticks(x, analysis)
    axs.legend()

    axs.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
    axs.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

    fig.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
```

The result is missing the "grouped bar" part of my plan :
[Results of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJA0U.png)

If now I try the insights given in : https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

I end up with this part of the code :

```
    x = np.arange(len(analysis))
    width = 0.35
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 5])
    rects1 = axs.bar(x-width/2, max_disp_iso, width, label='max_disp_iso')
    rects2 = axs.bar(x+width/2, max_disp_asb, width, label='max_disp_asb')
    axs.set_ylabel('Displacement (m)')
    axs.set_title('Max displacement')
    axs.set_xticks(x, analysis)
    axs.legend()

    axs.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
    axs.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

    fig.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
```

And the result if the following one :
[Second result that is still not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ0go.png)

Here, every analysis entry are used as an x_label for plotting. I would like to gather results that have the same analysis() string inside the same grouped bar in the chart.

Thanks in advance for any help provided !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robbie's answer (see : [Bar chart using Dictionaries in python using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130673/bar-chart-using-dictionaries-in-python-using-matplotlib)), I ended up using the following code :

```
# Sauvegarde des déplacements max dans des dataframes pour l'affichage
    df_iso = pd.DataFrame(max_disp_iso, index=['lis_iso','asb_iso']).transpose()
    df_asb = pd.DataFrame(max_disp_asb, index=['lis', 'asb_1', 'asb_2', 'asb_3']).transpose()

    util.folder_creation('max_disp')

    # Plot iso
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[10, 5])

    df_iso.plot.bar(ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel('Analysis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Displacement (m)')
    ax.grid(True)
    fig.tight_layout()

    fig.show()
    PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    PATH = os.path.join(PATH, "processed_res\\max_disp\\max_disp_iso.png")
    plt.savefig(PATH)
```

And the results are :
[image]